# Is it possible to fetch data from database before server is getting started?

Tags: database, spring

I am working on a Spring project. I want to use scheduler in it and want to schedule it on a variable date. This date has to be taken from database. Is it possible to fetch data from database before server is getting started?

Comment: Maybe you your answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49994397/11733759

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am not using Spring scheduler instead I am using Quartz API for scheduling.

Comment: Can you post your code that uses of Quartz API for scheduling?

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions come to my mind:

- `@PostConstruct` annotated method of some `@Component`:

  ```
  @Component
  public class MyBean 
  {

     @PostConstruct
     public void init() 
     {
        // Blocking DB call could go here
     }

  }
  ```
- [Application Events](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-application-events-and-listeners). For the `ApplicationReadyEvent`:

  ```
  @Component
  public class ApplicationReadyEventListener implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent>
  {

     @Override
     public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent event) 
     {
        // DB call could go here
        //
        // Notice that if this is a web services application, it
        // would potentially be serving requests while this method
        // is being executed
     }

  }
  ```