# Schedule job dynamically using record in Database in Springboot

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, scheduler, spring-scheduled

Need to send notifications to users using scheduler based on record in database,

We have Admins who can create Notification configuration from application. Based on that I need to run scheduler and send notifications to respective users who are falling in that notification criteria.

Specifications:

Springboot 2.7.15
Postgres 14

Comment: You can use QuartzScheduling https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.x/reference/html/integration.html#scheduling-quartz-cron

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot : Getting @Scheduled cron value from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37113327/spring-boot-getting-scheduled-cron-value-from-database)

Comment: No, If we want to use @Scheduled we need to define job before starting of application, once you running application you can't change the cron. I need to update cron expression based on updates happens.

Comment: [this](https://github.com/kagkarlsson/db-scheduler) should be easy to use

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand it correctly, is the database record user specific? Like can user A have a schedule of 1 minute and user B have a schedule of 2 minutes?

Comment: Then put the schedule on the database side, using [pg_cron](https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron)?