# Inject bean property in @Scheduled annotation

Tags: java, spring, annotations, scheduled-tasks

In my class I have an `@Autowired` bean which holds a cron expression in one of it's attributes.

In the same class I have a `@Scheduled` method, and I wish to set the cron expression to the bean's property.

I tried this already and it doesn't work

```
@Scheduled(cron = "#{propertyBean.cronExpression}")
```

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: here maybe : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15250928/how-to-change-springs-scheduled-fixeddelay-at-runtime
seems possible with spring boot

Answer (score 1):

This annotation worked for me:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${property.with.cron}")
```

With this in our spring profile/application.properties:

```
property.with.cron=*/10 * * * * *
```

We're using spring boot just fyi