# Spring boot Scheduler change cron expression run time/dynamically from application properties

Tags: spring-boot, cron

I have a spring boot app in an application.properties file add the Scheduler config task :
cron.every.minuts=0 */5 * ? * *  "Every 5 minutes"
I want to change this to "Every 10 minutes" in run time/dynamical cron expression,
I read cron expression with  @Scheduled(cron = "${cron.every.minuts}").

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/15250928/5225581