# Start spring scheduling based on some Event

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I need to start spring scheduling based on the constraint that my scheduler job will run every 5 seconds after a receive a jms message from other component.
What can be the possible way to implement /handle this scenario ,googled for the same but the solutions ask me to have a property in properties file for enabling scheduling which again is static approach.

Kindly suggest some solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:-

> [Thread.sleep(long delay)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long))  after receiving a message from JMS queue i.e. Thread.sleep(300000);

Basically your problem is not related to a scheduler. The message received from the queue is a trigger to invoke the job in your case.

Whereas the scheduled tasks are the ones which keeps repeating them periodically either based on [fixed delay](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleWithFixedDelay(java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) or [fixed interval](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) or at [specific time](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger).

> Your job is event based and not on time based so its not a scheduled
>   job.

Comment: after I get the message I have execute that method every 5 seconds .Is some thing not possible by aid of spring

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630539/scheduling-a-job-with-spring-programmitically-with-a-fixedrate-set-from-a-databa/14632758#14632758 check this link if it helps.