# Spring Boot - Alternative to Time.schedule?

Tags: java, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

I want to do something like `javascript`'s `setInterval(function, interval)`/`setTimeout(function, timeout)` in `Spring Boot`.

I found the `@Scheduled` annotation that has the `fixedRate` argument, but as an annotation I cannot change the rate dynamically (Or can I?)

For now I am using `java.util.Timer`, but I would rather use Spring. Is there a way?

Can I get a `Scheduler` instance and work with it dynamically?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution that works for my case.

In Main.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ConfigurationProperties
@EnableScheduling
public class Main {
    @Bean
    ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
        return new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }
}
```

In Service.java (Called from a rest controller):

```
@Service
public class Service {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Service.class);
    private final TaskScheduler scheduler;

    @Autowired
    public Service(TaskScheduler scheduler) {
        this.scheduler = scheduler;
    }

    public void startTask(int inteval) {
        scheduler.schedule(() -> log.info("Doing work"), triggerContext -> {
            if (some_condition) {
                ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now();

                return Date.from(now.plusSeconds(interval).toInstant());
            } else {
                // Stop the execution
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This solution works, but I'm not sure it is the correct way.

You are welcome to comment below, and I might change the solution if I get a suggestion I find helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You may use a `Trigger` which lets you dynamically control the next execution.  You need to implement `SchedulingConfigurer`, another answer covers exactly this:

[Scheduling a job with Spring programmatically (with fixedRate set dynamically)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630539/scheduling-a-job-with-spring-programmitically-with-a-fixedrate-set-from-a-databa/14632758#14632758)

**EDIT to answer comments**:

`nextExecutionTime` is called on and on and on... The next time the task (and nextExecutionTime) is called is defined by this:

```
nextExecutionTime.setTime(lastActualExecutionTime != null ? lastActualExecutionTime : new Date());
nextExecutionTime.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, numberOfMillisecondsBeforeCallingTheTask);
```

All you need to do is have this `numberOfMillisecondsBeforeCallingTheTask` value changed.

Example:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    public static int triggerDelay = 1000;

    @RequestMapping("/changetrigger/{val}")
    public void test(@PathVariable int val){
        this.triggerDelay = val;
    }
}
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class Launcher implements SchedulingConfigurer{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new SpringApplicationBuilder() //
        .sources(Launcher.class)//
        .run(args);
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    public Executor taskExecutor() {
        return Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(100);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
        taskRegistrar.setScheduler(taskExecutor());
         ;
        taskRegistrar.addTriggerTask(new TriggerTask(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("blah");
                System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
            }
        }, new Trigger() {
            @Override
            public Date nextExecutionTime(TriggerContext triggerContext) {
                Calendar nextExecutionTime = new GregorianCalendar();
                nextExecutionTime.setTime(new Date());
                nextExecutionTime.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, MyController.triggerDelay);
                System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
                return nextExecutionTime.getTime();
            }}));
    }
}
```

Notice how the dynamic value `MyController.triggerDelay` is used for the next execution. So if you change the number, the next execution time will be changed. You'll see if you put a breakpoint inside `nextExecutionTime`.

Comment: Looks good, but it only runs on application startup, doesn't it? I need to start and stop scheduled tasks all the time

Comment: I found a solution thanks to you, but it is a bit different. probably more suited to my needs. I voted up, and I will add my own solution to get some feedback about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Scheduled(fixedRateString = "${spring.boot.schedule.rate}")` for your case, where the `spring.boot.schedule.rate` is the external properties in `application.properties`

spring.boot.schedule.rate=5000

*Misunderstand the question, above is just the externalize the properties.*

For the dynamic solution, maybe this should be work, using the spEL in the annonation:

```
@Service
public class ScheduledService {
    @Autowired
    private FixRateProperty fixRateProperty;

    @Scheduled(fixedRateString = "#{fixRateProperty.fixRate}")
    private void reportCurrentTime() {
        System.out.println(new Date());;
    }
}
```

This is the `FixRateProperty`

```
@Component
public class FixRateProperty {
    private Long fixRate = 500L;

    public Long getFixRate() {
        return fixRate;
    }

    public void setFixRate(Long fixRate) {
        this.fixRate = fixRate;
    }
}
```

so you can externalize the rate in the properties or set the `fixRate` somewhere.

Comment: This is not a dynamic solution. it is determined on application start, and it is a global constant. If I want to run multiple tasks with different schedules it will not work.

Comment: @Algosub sorry, I update the answer, hope this will help you.

Comment: This is still not what I need. Please look at the answer I posted, it might clarify what I need. I don't know if my solution is a good one, but it works for me. You are welcome to comment on it and I am open to suggestions.