# Change method call sheduling without rebuilding war

Tags: java, lombok

Currently I'm working on schedule my method. At this moment I have solution like below:

```
@Scheduled(cron = {cron.from.properties})
public void resetCache() {
   // ...
}
```

And now I need to be able to change schedule with cron from properties without rebuilding war. Do you maybe know any working alternative for above solution? Thanks

Comment: This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/14632758/2224047

Comment: Please fix your tags. It has nothing to do with Lombok; it's probably spring. See the linked question.