# Spring batch: How to change the fixed delay of a job dynamically at run time

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, schedule, job-scheduling

My requirement:

I have a spring batch job with fixed delay as 5 sec. So my job will poll a web service for every 5 sec and based on the response(case when I get 200 ok status ) I need to put the current job to **sleep for 30 seconds** and after that it has to resume polling the web service every **5 seconds**

Is there any way to configure this dynamically during run time ?? I need to change the fixed delay property in **Reader part**.

My sample TestJob config:

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000L) // I need to change this property dynamically @ runtime 
    public void TestEventScheduler() {
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("TestDataJobTime", System.currentTimeMillis()) 
                .toJobParameters();
        try {
            jobLauncher.run(TestDataJob, jobParameters);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with spring batch but with spring integration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many approaches you could do here:

1. Register `Trigger` bean and update it every time with your delay.
   You can also look into [CompoundTrigger](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-integration/4.3.0.M1/api/org/springframework/integration/util/CompoundTrigger.html) to simplify your logic.
2. Instead of using `@Scheduled` annotation at the end of your batch job you can have a listener or output channel which will add your batchJob once more to execution channel with specific delay.

Also you can check similar problem's answer: [Scheduling a job with Spring programmatically (with fixedRate set dynamically)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630539/scheduling-a-job-with-spring-programmatically-with-fixedrate-set-dynamically/14632758#14632758)

Comment: Thanks Igor Konoplyanko, I will try your suggested answer :)

Comment: I guess Option 2 will be easier, I will use either **StepExecutionListener or
ItemReadListener**. But how I can add delay ? can I use **Thread.sleep(some delay)**  within the @AfterStep annotated method or do we have any other way to do this ?