# Schedule a new Date for a task every iteration - Java Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, task, schedule

I need to schedule to a new Date for everytime a task it's executed.
I've seen many examples where the period or interval is set by millis and stays for every iteration but i can't find any that takes a date parameter for next execution

I tried the @Scheduled annotation since I am working with Spring, but I do not know if there is a possibility to pass a parameter.

Examples i've seen

Example 1:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 20000)
    public void scheduler() {
        log.info("scheduler");
        log.info("Current Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        log.info("Current Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
}
```

Example 2:

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(myRunnable, 10, 10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

I expect to read a Date from a db table to schedule my task for new iteration

Ty for the help!

**Edit**

Note: There will also be a time when I need to decide where to stop the next iteration, so I'm trying to call the schedule task by a method

Comment: Check the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630539/scheduling-a-job-with-spring-programmatically-with-fixedrate-set-dynamically/14632758#14632758

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I avoid using Spring, so I cannot help you there. But I can guide you through the use of `ScheduledExecutorService` to accomplish your goal.

## `ScheduledExecutorService::schedule​( Runnable command, long delay, TimeUnit unit )`

You are partially correct about the [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html): Two of its three scheduling strategies are designed to keep regular intervals between runs:

- [`scheduleAtFixedRate​`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.lang.Runnable,long,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit))
- [`scheduleWithFixedDelay​`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleWithFixedDelay(java.lang.Runnable,long,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit))

But the third strategy lets you set the next run with any amount of delay you wish.

- [`schedule​( Runnable command, long delay, TimeUnit unit )`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#schedule(java.lang.Runnable,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit))
- [`schedule​( Callable<V> callable, long delay, TimeUnit unit )`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#schedule(java.util.concurrent.Callable,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit))

If you want a single task to be executed repeatedly but not concurrently, use a [single-thread executor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor()).

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor() ;
```

On that [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html), schedule your task. And make the last step of that task be the chore of scheduling the next occurrence. We have a perpetual motion machine, each time the task runs, it schedules the next run, indefinitely.

Define your `Runnable` task.

```
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run ( ) {
            // Do the work of this task.
            ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.systemDefault() ); // Capture the current moment.
            System.out.println( "Current moment: " + zdt ); // Report the current moment.
            // Schedule the next run of this task.
            scheduledExecutorService.schedule( this , 10L , TimeUnit.SECONDS );  // Delay will not be *exactly* this amount of time due to interruptions of scheduling cores on CPU and threads by the JVM and host OS.
        }
    };
```

Then run it.

```
    // Jump-start this perpetual motion machine.
    scheduledExecutorService.schedule( runnable , 0L , TimeUnit.SECONDS );  // Start immediately, no delay.
```

Let the executor do its work repeatedly for a certain length of time. Sleep the main thread while the executor service runs on a background thread(s).

```
    try {
        Thread.sleep( TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis( 2 ) );  // Let our app, and the executor, run for 2 minutes, then shut them both down.
    } catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Remember to **always shutdown the executor**. Otherwise its background thread(s) may continue running long after your main app has exited.

```
    scheduledExecutorService.shutdown();
    System.out.println( "INFO - Executor shutting down. App exiting. " + ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.systemDefault() ) );
```

Tip: Always wrap your `Runnable` code in a try-catch for all exceptions. Any uncaught exception reaching the executor service will cause the executor to immediately halt, and halt silently.

```
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run ( ) {
            try {
                // Do the work of this task.
                ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.systemDefault() ); // Capture the current moment.
                System.out.println( "Current moment: " + zdt ); // Report the current moment.
                // Schedule the next run of this task.
                scheduledExecutorService.schedule( this , 10L , TimeUnit.SECONDS );  // Delay will not be *exactly* this amount of time due to interruptions of scheduling cores on CPU and threads by the JVM and host OS.
            } catch ( Exception e ) {
                // TODO: Handle unexpected exeption.
                System.out.println( "ERROR - unexpected exception caught on its way to reaching a scheduled executor service. Message # 55cbae82-8492-4638-9630-60c5b28ad876." );
            }
        }
    };
```

> I expect to read a Date from a db table to schedule my task for new iteration

Never use `Date` or `Calendar`. Those terrible classes were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* with the adoption of JSR 310.

As of JDBC 4.2 and later, we can directly exchange *java.time* objects with the database.

```
OffsetDateTime now = OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
OffsetDateTime later = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
if( ! now.isBefore( later ) ) { … } // Verify the future moment is indeed in the future.
```

Calculate elapsed time, the amount of time we want to delay until our next scheduled run.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( now , odt ) ;
long seconds = d.toSeconds() ; // Truncates any fractional second.
```

Use that number of seconds to schedule the next run.

```
scheduledExecutorService.schedule( this , seconds , TimeUnit.SECONDS );
```

So the `Runnable` now looks like this.

```
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run ( ) {
            try {
                // Do the work of this task.
                ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.systemDefault() ); // Capture the current moment.
                System.out.println( "Current moment: " + zdt ); // Report the current moment.
                // Schedule the next run of this task.
                OffsetDateTime now = OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
                … do your database query …
                OffsetDateTime later = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
                if( ! now.isBefore( later ) ) { … } // Verify the future moment is indeed in the future.
                Duration d = Duration.between( now , odt ) ;
                long seconds = d.toSeconds() ; // Truncates any fractional second.
                scheduledExecutorService.schedule( this , seconds , TimeUnit.SECONDS );  // Delay will not be *exactly* this amount of time due to interruptions of scheduling cores on CPU and threads by the JVM and host OS.
            } catch ( Exception e ) {
                // TODO: Handle unexpected exeption.
                System.out.println( "ERROR - unexpected exception caught on its way to reaching a scheduled executor service. Message # 55cbae82-8492-4638-9630-60c5b28ad876." );
            }
        }
    };
```

Here is the complete example in a single `.java` file but without the database query.

```
package work.basil.example;

import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.time.*;

public class ScheduleNextTaskExample {
    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        ScheduleNextTaskExample app = new ScheduleNextTaskExample();
        app.doIt();
    }

    private void doIt ( ) {
        ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run ( ) {
                try {
                    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.systemDefault() ); // Capture the current moment.
                    System.out.println( "Current moment: " + zdt ); // Report the current moment.
                    scheduledExecutorService.schedule( this , 10L , TimeUnit.SECONDS );  // Delay will not be *exactly* this amount of time due to interruptions of scheduling cores on CPU and threads by the JVM and host OS.
                } catch ( Exception e ) {
                    // TODO: Handle unexpected exeption.
                    System.out.println( "ERROR - unexpected exception caught on its way to reaching a scheduled executor service. Message # 55cbae82-8492-4638-9630-60c5b28ad876." );
                }
            }
        };

        // Jump-start this perpetual motion machine.
        scheduledExecutorService.schedule( runnable , 0L , TimeUnit.SECONDS );  // Start immediately, no delay.
        try {
            Thread.sleep( TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis( 2 ) );  // Let our app, and the executor, run for 2 minutes, then shut them both down.
        } catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        scheduledExecutorService.shutdown();
        System.out.println( "INFO - Executor shutting down. App exiting. " + ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.systemDefault() ) );

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can register a new `TimerTask`, execute the desired logic, and register a new `TimerTask` at the completion of the desired logic:

```
public class Starter {

    public void execute() {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        Date firstExecutionDate = // ... compute ...
        timer.schedule(
            new RepeatedTimerTask(timer, this::toDoUponEachExecution, this::findNextExecutionDate),
            firstExecutionDate
        );
    }

    private Date findNextExecutionDate() {
        // ... compute ...
    }

    private void toDoUponEachExecution() {
        // ... do something ...
    }
}

public class RepeatedTimerTask extends TimerTask {

    private final Timer timer;
    private final Runnable logic;
    private final Supplier<Date> nextExecution;

    public RepeatedTimerTask(Timer timer, Runnable logic, Supplier<Date> nextExecution) {
        this.timer = timer;
        this.logic = logic;
        this.nextExecution = nextExecution;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        logic.run();
        timer.schedule(this, nextExecution.get());
    }
}
```

Comment: The use of `Timer` is pretty much obsoleted by the [Executor framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html). Especially so if in a Servlet or Jakarta EE environment.  This schedule-next-run approach shown here could just as well be done with an executor.