# incompatible types. Found: 'org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value', required: 'long'

Tags: java, spring, inject

I have a scheduler to clean the DB

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = @Value("#{new Long('${clean_up.period}')}"))
public void cleanStatInfoTable() {
    List<StateInfo> infoLis=stateInfoRepository.findAllByCreatedDateBefore(LocalDateTime.now().minusHours(1));
    stateInfoRepository.deleteInBatch(infoLis);
}
```

But it produce compilation error

> Incompatible types. Found:
>   'org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value', required: 'long'

I also tried the form     `@Scheduled(fixedDelay = @Value("${obi.payments.state_info.clean_up.period}"))`
but still the same issue

How can i inject a `long` value into the `fixedDelay` property in `Scheduled` annotation ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scheduling a job with Spring programmatically (with fixedRate set dynamically)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630539/scheduling-a-job-with-spring-programmatically-with-fixedrate-set-dynamically)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `fixedDelayString` instead what you have now. You are making things overly complex.

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${clean_up.period}"))
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this :

```
@Value("${clean_up.period}")
private Long delay;

------
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = delay)
```

Comment: It doesn't work because `fixedDelay` must be a constant.