# How to schedule Cron Expression at Run time?

Tags: java, spring

I want to schedule cron at Runtime. I am fetching my cron list from database based on that list i want to schedule cron expression. Can some one help me out with this.

```
  package com.app.schedule.schedular; 
    import org.quartz.SchedulerException;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
    import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
    
    import com.app.schedule.controller.AlertController;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
    
    @Configuration
    @EnableScheduling
    public class Schedular {
        
        @Autowired AlertController alertController;
    
        @Scheduled(cron = "0 23 17 * * ?")
        public void scheduleTaskUsingCronExpression() throws JsonProcessingException, SchedulerException {
         
                alertController.getAlertList();
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: You can check this answer and see if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630539/scheduling-a-job-with-spring-programmitically-with-a-fixedrate-set-from-a-databa/14632758#14632758

Comment: if you use quartz you can dynamic register job

Comment: @TongChen Can you share an example of how to do it using Quartz

Answer (score 0):

At runtime when you get your cron expression from database or cron expression modified,you need two steps to change cron task.The below code just for reference.

First call `removeScheduler` remove exist Scheduler use old cron expression,then use `addScheduler` add new Scheduler who use new cron expression from database.

```
public class ScheduleTaskManager {
    private Map<TriggerKey, Scheduler> schedulerMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    
    public void removeScheduler(String triggerName) throws Exception {
        Scheduler scheduler = schedulerMap.get(TriggerKey.triggerKey(triggerName));
        if (scheduler != null) {
            scheduler.shutdown();
            schedulerMap.remove(TriggerKey.triggerKey(triggerName));
        }
    }

    public void addScheduler(String triggerName, String cronExpression, JobDetail jobDetail) throws Exception {
        Scheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();

        Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
            .withIdentity(TriggerKey.triggerKey(triggerName))
            .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(cronExpression))
            .build();
        scheduler.start();

        scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);

        schedulerMap.put(TriggerKey.triggerKey(triggerName), scheduler);
    }
}
```