# Read constant for java @Schedule from configuration

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

Hello What I want to achieve is have a scheduler setup so that it runs every X minutes, this x minutes should be read from a configuration file. I'm getting a compilation error saying "Attribute value must be a constant". Can you suggest me the best approach on a situation like this.

I have tried out few approaches.

1. using a constructor

   ```
   @Singleton
   @LocalBean
   public class Scheduler {

    final String SCHEDULER;

    public Scheduler() {

        ConfigResources configResources = ConfigResources.getConfigResources();
        SCHEDULER = configResources.getEolApiScheduler();
    }

    @Schedule(minute= SCHEDULER, hour="*")
    public void retryEndOfLeaseSchedule() {

        System.out.println("inside retryEndOfLeaseSchedule ");

    }
   ```
2. using a static block

   ```
   @Singleton
   @LocalBean
   public class Scheduler {

    final static String SCHEDULER;

    static {

        ConfigResources configResources = ConfigResources.getConfigResources();
        SCHEDULER = configResources.getEolApiScheduler();
    }

    @Schedule(minute= SCHEDULER, hour="*")
    public void retryEndOfLeaseSchedule() {

        System.out.println("inside retryEndOfLeaseSchedule ");

    }
   ```

Comment: Please post the actual code, don't use images. [Reasons why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @Alex.T, edited, any idea about the answer ? thanks in advance

Comment: I usually handle this scenario in `Spring` by using a `Trigger`, similarly to this [another similar question, but on spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630539/scheduling-a-job-with-spring-programmatically-with-fixedrate-set-dynamically). I'm not sure how it would be done directly in Java (or another library).