# How to update the cron scheduler from the database without restarting spring batch application?

Tags: spring-batch

Goal:
Dynamically get the cron scheduler from the database and take those changes in without the need to restart spring batch application.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scheduling a job with Spring programmatically (with fixedRate set dynamically)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630539/scheduling-a-job-with-spring-programmatically-with-fixedrate-set-dynamically)

Comment: I'm running multiple jobs how can I trigger task with specific job?