# Compile error attribute must be a constant expression when set fixedDelay value in Spring Scheduled annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to read fixedDelay from a property file so doing below.

```
@Bean
public Runnable method(){  
static final int delay= properties.getConnectionConfig().getConnectMonitorDelay();
        return new Runnable() {
            @Override
            @Scheduled(fixedDelay = delay)
            public void run() {}
       };
}
```

properties.getConnectionConfig().getConnectMonitorDelay() already return a primitive int but i am getting below compile error.

> The value for annotation attribute Scheduled.fixedDelay must be a
> constant expression

How to get rid of the compile error?

Answer (score 0):

Java annotations take compile time constants, which are defined as final primitives or strings.

In Spring Boot, you can use an application property directly with [fixedDelayString](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html#fixedDelayString--), [fixedRateString](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html#fixedRateString--), [initialDelayString](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html#initialDelayString--)  properties.

```java
@Bean
public Runnable method(){
    return new Runnable() {
        @Override
        @Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${connection-config.connect-monitor-delay}")
        public void run() {
            // ..
        }
    };
}
```

Check out this link for more different approaches:

[Scheduling a job with Spring programmatically (with fixedRate set dynamically)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630539/scheduling-a-job-with-spring-programmatically-with-fixedrate-set-dynamically/14632758)

Comment: Java annotations take compile time constants, which are defined as final primitives -> why would code i asked giving compile error then

Comment: I may not be able to focus, because when you run your code first; don't you get *`illegal start of expression`* error because you are declaring static local variable in method?