# How to reload a Spring Boot bean such that it refreshes the @Schedule attribute, when the attribute is called from a jpa repository?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cron

I have a job which I am scheduling, with the cron value in a jpa repository. When **getCronValue()** is called in **@Scheduled(cron="#{@getCronValue}")** , it successfully returns the cron value from the database. When the application is live and I update the value in the repository, it does correctly print the value I have updated it to in the logger I have below.

```
    @Scheduled(cron="#{@getCronValue}")
    public void testCronJob()
    {
            logger.info("CRON EXPRESSION: " + getCronValue());
    }
```

The issue is that while it is returning the correct value, the schedule is not actually changing. Once the application is running, if the value was originally 1 seconds, and I change the schedule to every 10 seconds, it continues to **run** every 1 seconds, while **printing** the new value of 10 seconds which is now in the repository.

Example output:

*Application starts*

*1 second passes*

```
CRON EXPRESSION: * * * * * *
```

Now I manually go into the repository and change the cron expression to once every 10 seconds

*1 second passes*

```
CRON EXPRESSION: */10 * * * * *
```

*1 second passes*

```
CRON EXPRESSION: */10 * * * * *
```

Here is the rest of the job class for reference. I was investigating if @RefreshScope would help but I lack the understanding, and the research I've found tends to be referencing local property files, which this is avoiding since the attribute is in a repository.

```
@RefreshScope
@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty("cron.config.job.enabled")
public class CronConfigJob
{

    ServiceA service;

    @Autowired
    public CronConfigJob(ServiceA service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @Autowired
    private RepositoryA repository;

    @Bean()
    public String getCronValue()
    {

        String result = repository.findByJobName("CronConfigJob").getJobCronExpression();
        return result;
    }

    @Scheduled(cron="#{@getCronValue}")
    public void testCronJob()
    {
                logger.info("CRON EXPRESSION: " + getCronValue());
    }
```

Comment: I modified [the answer to this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630539/scheduling-a-job-with-spring-programmatically-with-fixedrate-set-dynamically) for my use case, only thing that worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must use the Trigger class, configureTask, Runnable, etc.. Detailed very well in the link in the comment.