# spring boot scheduling based on configuration file

Tags: java, spring-boot, etl, scheduling

I have developed a number of REST APIs using Spring Boot but now I need to developed a different type of application and I got confused. In my previous projects ***args*** (command line arguments) were not used, but now I am developing an ETL application that should should receive a configuration file (JSON or YAML) in the command line and based on its content build a scheduler and adjust ETL tasks with connections and other attributes specified there.
So, I have my main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class EtlProcessor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EtlProcessor.class, args);
    }
}
```

as well as configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class EtlConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private TaskScheduler scheduler;
    
    @Autowired
    private EtlTask task;
    
    public void configure(String configFile) {
        
    }
}
```

I know that Spring boot will register and instantiate all components, but can't figure out how do I pass first element of **args** array to the configure function and initiate the processing. Any tips will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by a multi-step process:

1. Define a Java class the represents the content of the yml/yaml configuration file.
2. Create a bean method in a configuration class that takes the following method parameter: `@Value("${etlConfigFile}")`.
3. In this method use Jackson to map the file identified by etlConfigFile to the java class mentioned in step 1). See [this](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-yaml).
4. Inject this bean into your EtlTask or your EtlConfiguration class.
5. When you start your app add the following to your startup command: `-DetlConfigFile=<path_to_configuration_file`.

Comment: I do know how to process YAML or JSON with Jackson. What I didn't quite get is points 2 and 4. I already have Java class representing config file content, but part of  it(scheduling) need to be used by EtlConfiguration class and another one by EtlTask (JDBC connector, etc.)
Also, are you saying that args from main method cannot be passed to other classes?

Comment: An example of 2) would be ```@Bean
  public ConfigFile configFile(@Value("${etlConfigFile}") String etlConfigFile)``` and  for 4) just autowire or constructor inject the ConfigFile. ConfigFile in this case would be the java representation of the contents of the yaml file.

Comment: I did try your suggestion but it does not work for me.
I am getting 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'etlConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'config.file' in value "${config.file}"
I do have     @Value("${config.file}")
    private String configFileName;
and -Dconfig.file=/my/config/file/path.json

Comment: Not sure why yours doesn't work. I have a working sample project that successfully obtains the config.file value via command line, creates a bean with the contents of the file, and injects the bean into another class.

Comment: Here is how I created the bean within a configuration class:
```@Bean
  public ConfigFile configFile(@Value("${config.file}") String configFile) throws IOException {
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());

    mapper.findAndRegisterModules();

    return mapper.readValue(new File(configFile), ConfigFile.class);
  }```

Answer (score -1):

To access the file from main args and pass it into Configuration Bean, you can read the file path as variable via `@Value`. This is an example for it

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class EtlConfiguration {

  @Value("${schedule.config.path}")
  private String configPath;

  @Bean
  public Object configureBeanObject() throws IOException {
    InputStream targetStream = new FileInputStream(Paths.get(configPath).toFile());

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    var jsonValues = mapper.readValue(targetStream, new TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>>() {
    });

    System.out.println("jsonValues:");
    System.out.println(jsonValues);

    // If else condition to get the final Map
    // For read the yaml file
    /*Fiel file = new File(YamlBeansFileReader.class.getClassLoader().getResource(path).getFile());
    YamlReader yamlReader = new YamlReader(new FileReader(filePath));
    Map yamlProperties = (Map) yamlReader.read();

    System.out.println("yamlProperties:");
    yamlProperties.getSource().forEach((s, o) -> System.out.println(s + ": " + o));*/

    return null;
  }
}
```

```
java -jar -Dschedule.config.path=path/to/json-or-yaml-file.
```

My json file.

```
{
    "property1": [
        {"nested": 2},
        {"nested": 5}
    ],
    "property2": "abc"
}
```

And here is the results:

```
jsonValues:{property2=abc, property1=[{nested=2}, {nested=5}]}
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I need.
1. I got not application.properties file, but either JSON or YAML file that has much more info than just cron expression. configure() method suppose to process this file and call setters on EtlTask instance to set its properties. After that it will call appropriate schedule method based on configuration - either fixed rate, or cron expression.
2. How configure() method will be called?

Comment: I think you're asking for a big task not simply a question. 1. Yes you can either have a `.properties` or `.yml` in the external folder.  Also, it can include a set of properties. 2. You should look for the scheduling programmatically in spring-boot refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630539/scheduling-a-job-with-spring-programmatically-with-fixedrate-set-dynamically).

Comment: I think I asked a simple question: How to pass arguments from main method to another class method in spring boot? Properties file is not what I want.

Comment: @GaryGreenberg sorry for misunderstanding your question, I updated the answer. Hope it's clear now

Comment: Sorry, for late response (I was on vacation) but I still have not quite get it. Who is suppose to call this configureBeanObject() method and why it should be annotated as Bean? I did try to follow your suggestion, but nothing was scheduled.

Comment: You was asking that `How to pass arguments from main method to another class method in spring boot?` then now you say nothing is schedule. You're such unreasonable, I'd save my energy rather than answer your questions.

Comment: If you do not want to answer my question, I can't force you.
My original question was about scheduling the ETL task based on configuration file passed as command line argument. You said that I can't passed args from main method to configuration class but have to declare property (with -D) instead. I did follow your suggestion and in the unit test, where I am explicitly calling method annotated with @Bean, configuration file was processed correctly, but when I am running my application it looks like this method is not being called, therefore the ETL task was not scheduled for execution.